# OnBootReceiver works, but doesn't find AlarmReceiver

Tags: java, android, cordova, mobile

I'm trying to set up an alarm receiver right after booting. Therefore, i have an OnBootReceiver that should register the alarm. The onBootReceiver works and it gets called, but somehow it cannot find my AlarmReceiver class.

OnBootReceiver which succesfully starts after booting:

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "OnBootReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called");

        Intent i = new Intent(context, com.packagenames.AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        time.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), time.getTimeInMillis(), pi);

    }

}
```

As you you can see, it configures the alarm tries to invoke com.packagenames.AlarmReceiver.class. This class exists and is located in the same package:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "alarm received");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, com.packagename.DataService.class);
        i.putExtra("action", "process");
        context.startService(i);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, i get the following error:

> 02-03 09:22:25.344: W/ActivityManager(103): Unable to start service
>   Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.phonegap.packagename/.AlarmReceiver (has extras)
>   }: not found

The Android Manifest looks like this

```
<application>

// activities etc

        <receiver
            android:name="com.phonegap.packagename.OnBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="OnBootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.phonegap.packagename.AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

Do you see a mistake? Maybe I forgot something?

Thanks

edit: in the manifest, I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

in order to make the OnBootReceiver work. Do I need something similar for the alarm?

Comment: You shouldn't have to add anything for your Alarm.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example/8801990#8801990][1]
 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example/8801990#8801990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you use getBroadcast instead of getService when creating a pending intent ?

Answer (score 0):

The whole receiver stuff ONLY works if you application is NOT installed on a SD card. Add this to your manifest file to do so:

android:installLocation="internalOnly"